# JavaScript Manipulation-Secure Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, input

Most of the `big` sites have these special inputs (Type Text for instance, but also TextArea) where you cannot insert/change the value via JavaScript.

For instance: Let's take a look at the instagram login: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher

When you change the value with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "TestValue"
```

The "TextValue"-Text gets inserted into the input-field, but as soon as you focus the input, it disappears.

- How is that done?
- How secure is that and, except for some manipulation between client/server or before the request is sent?
- What options would users have to bypass this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: They most likely store the last valid value and compare it to the current one when the user focuses the input.

Comment: @nickzoum Thank you, but what is a "last valid value"? - How can you know, which value was inserted by JavaScript and which one was typed by a user?

Comment: Changing the value from a script will not trigger the `change` event.

Comment: I think that most of the big companies use frameworks as react for example, those frameworks sometimes prevents injection attacks 
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks
That helps that a user cannot write anything that is not implicitly indicated in the application.

Comment: Also even if you can placehold a text in the input field, as Nick said, that won't trigger the change event and does not change the state in the component.

Comment: If they do not want the value to change, I highly doubt they use that field in any way.

Comment: how do you change a value of instagram input field by javascript?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic That's something I'd like to know too.